# Unique constraint vs pre checking

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I use SQL Server 2008, and I have a table with a column of type varchar(X) which I want to have unique values.

What is the best way to achieve that? Should I use unique constraint and catch an exception, or should I pre-check before inserting a new value?

One issue, the application is used by many users so I guess that pre-checking might result in race condition, in case that two users will insert the same values.

Thanks

Comment: Related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889843/unique-constraint-vs-checking-before-insert

Answer (score 10):

Race condition is an excellent point to be aware of.

Why not do both? - pre-check so you can give good feedback to the user, but definitely have the unique constraint as your ultimate safeguard.

Comment: When it comes to data validation, redundancy isn't necessarily a bad thing. Check up front for a nicer interface, check at the back end for guaranteed integrity.

Comment: I am not aware of the race condition. Can you please tell me why one should do both when the back-end checks everything. Thanks.

Comment: @araqnid - I am unable to see how redundancy is helpful here.

Answer (score 4):

Let the DB do the work for you. Create the unique constraint.

Comment: Is there any scenario where one method would be better than the other ? I have posted a related question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889843/unique-constraint-vs-checking-before-insert Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a requirement that the values be unique --- then a constraint is the only guaranteed way to achieve that.  reliable so-called pre-checking will require a level of locking that will make that part of your system essentially single user.

Answer (score 3):

Use a constraint (UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY). That way the key is enforced for every application. You could perform additional checks and handling in a store procedure if you need to - either before or after the insert.