# Vote Up/Like System for posts using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've searched for this on stackoverflow and while I've found something along these lines, I haven't found anything that really helps me, so I'll ask the question myself.

So I'm trying to implement a like button for images on my site. But I'm having a little trouble figuring out how it goes.

So far, I have this on the SQLI side of things :

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists `likes` (
         `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         `image_id` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
         `liker_username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
          `liked_unliked` enum('0','1') NOT NULL, DEFAULT '0'
           PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        );
```

Where `id` is the id of the like,
`image_id` is the id of the image being liked,
`liker_username` is the username of the user clicking the like button,
`liked_unliked` is whether or not that user has liked the image (1 for liked, 0 for unliked [to make sure users only vote once]).

I have the image_id already stored in a `photos` table.

I've been told to put a unique index on `liker_username` and `image_id` in order to prevent users from liking an image multiple times, but I just want a second opinion.

So...is what I have so far even correct? Like I said, I'm trying to get it so that users can click the like button and like the image, but only once. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need to make sure that any (image_id, liker_username) combination appears only once. You can do this in your application logic, or, within mysql remove the id key and build a composite key with the pair (image_id, liker_username). Oh sorry, your unique index would do just that :) Well, this looks fine to me, then !

Comment: Without seeing any php code, this is nothing more than table to us. Personally, I would probably not store the user name in this table, but store the user_id as a foreign key to your users table (assuming one exists).

Comment: It saves time in programming. On the other hand you will get a DB-Error (consider what errors you want to handle).

Comment: As far as I know, there are only two options to implement this constraint. Therefore, I see this question as a duplicate of [UNIQUE constraint vs checking before INSERT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889843/unique-constraint-vs-checking-before-insert). +1 for a well-formed question nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're on the right track.

Like another user said, you might consider having a `users` table with user data and ids, and put the foreign key liker_user_id in your `likes` table. Your image id could also be a foreign key, with images stored in an `images` table.

You may consider allowing anonymous votes, one per i address, adding the ip address to the DB if the user is not logged in. You can get the users ip address with:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```